# How can I connect a database entry and storage entry in Firebase?

Tags: java, android

I have two functions working fine in an android app with Firebase. I can upload an image to my storage and I can add attributes to my database, but how do I build a relationship between the two entries.

Here's my database code:

```
private void addCar(){
    String make = editTextMake.getText().toString().trim();
    String model = editTextModel.getText().toString().trim();
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString().trim();

    Car car = new Car(make, model, description);

    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(car);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

And here is my storage code:

```
private void uploadImage() {

    if (filePath != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(uploadActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(uploadActivity.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I'd like a User to be able to pick an image of a car, enter the attributes relating to that image like Make/Model and press an upload button to enter both into Firebase, while knowing that the specific image is related to the specific attributes.

Comment: first of all upload image in storage .. then after that url put into your firebase database

Comment: So there's no way to do the actions simultaneously? @NikunjParadva

Comment: no actions provided by firebase storage like your requirements

Comment: @NikunjParadva OK, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

```
 StorageReference filess= storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID());
    filess.putFile(url)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.e("url", taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() + ":");

                   // Get Url from here and add to your Database
                    addFirebase(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                }
            });
```

**Firebase insert data**

```
     private void addFirebase(String url){
           String make = editTextMake.getText().toString().trim();
           String model = editTextModel.getText().toString().trim();
           String description = getText().toString().trim();
            Car car = new Car(make, model, description,url);

           FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
           databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(car);

           Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}